# Локальный произвольно конструируемый массив объектов C++

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, у меня возник вроде бы тупой вопрос, на который я не смог найти ответ ни в гугле, ин в MSDN. Как определить локальный массив объектов, которые конструировались бы не конструктором по умолчанию?  
Пусть у нас есть:

```
class A
{
    A(){};
    A(int i){};
    ~A(){};
};
```

И нам нужно определить локальный массив объектов класса A, скажем в 100 штук, а сконструированы они должны быть конструктором A(int), со значением параметра 5.

```
A a[100](5);//не компилируется
A a(5)[100];//не компилируется
```

Пришла сразу же безумная идея сделать:

```
A a[100];
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    a[i].A::~A();
    a[i].A::A(5);
}
```

Но ведь должен же быть в языке и какой-то нормальный способ сделать это?  
Что-то не мой сегодня день, сделал правку старой копии, потерял предыдущие изменения. Напишу коротко:

```
A a[100] = A(1.0);
```

Так сделать нельзя, потому что:

**8.5.1 Aggregates**

*1. An aggregate is an array or a class (clause 9) with no user-declared constructors (12.1), no private or protected
non-static data members (clause 11), no base classes (clause 10), and no virtual functions (10.3).  

 2. When an aggregate is initialized the initializer can contain an initializer-clause consisting of a braceenclosed,
comma-separated list of initializer-clauses for the members of the aggregate, written in increasing
subscript or member order.*

То что компилирует gcc в этой ситуации не должно компилироваться по стандарту.

Answer (score 3):

*Массивы* объектов на стеке - это не самая лучшая идея.

Правильный способ записать то, что вы хотите - воспользоваться [**std::vector**.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/vector/)

```
std::vector<A> a(100, A(5));
```

Comment: мне этот момент интересен в исследовательских целях, не в практических, получается в языке нет возможности определить массив недефолтно конструируемых объектов на стеке?

Comment: C++ сам по себе - не самая лучшая идея. Многие прграммы на нем напоминают высказывание:

*сначала создаем себе проблемы, а потом героически преодолеваем их*

Comment: @avp, то же самое можно сказать про некоторые аспекты программирования на С.

Comment: @mikillskegg, безусловно так. А что Вы хотите от макроассемблера с типами (это я про Си) ?

Comment: Хочу возможности перегрузки функций. Си это вполне реально сделать. И было бы очень удобно. А еще можно шаблонов. Было бы совсем хорошо.

Comment: С++ - это гениальная идея. Низкоуровневый язык с возможностями высокоуровневого программирования. Немного непродуман. Но постепенно исправляется.

Comment: Техника программирования с щаблонами в Си существует. 

Я нашел ее [здесь](https://github.com/swenson/sort) и реализовал [здесь](http://code.google.com/p/yamsort/source/browse/yamsort_tmpl.h), пример использования [тут](http://code.google.com/p/yamsort/source/browse/data_yamsort.c)

Comment: Вскользь посмотрев, понял, что делали через макросы. Так?

Comment: Так. Не сам изобрел. По производительности оказалось превосходно (по сравнению с qsort стилем).

Answer (score 0):

Например, так:

```
A a[100] = A(1.0);
```

**Дополнено из комментария**.

```
class A {
public:
    int z;
    A(int x) {
        z = x;
    };
};

int main()
{
    A a[3] = A(6);
}
```

Все работает. Вообще говоря, вроде это обычный вызов конструктора 3 раза.

Comment: Так нельзя.

Comment: Перенесено в ответ.

Comment: Какой это компилятор, и, главное, какой язык? Насколько я знаю, в C++ нельзя инициализировать массив объектом.

Comment: компилятор гцц, язык с++. Массив объектом инициализировать нельзя, конечно, но тут работает конструктор. Т.е. вообще говоря эта запись аналогична следующей:
A a[0] = A(6);
A a[1] = A(6);
A a[2] = A(6);

Comment: Видимо, специфика компилятора, VC++ не компилирует такие штуки...

Comment: VC должен понимать, посмотрите, может где-то опечатка у Вас.

Comment: Нет, опечаток у меня нет, VC++ не компилирует подобные вещи, и насколько я помню, массив при определении нельзя инициализировать чем-либо кроме списка инициализаторов, я сейчас не готов сослаться на стандарт, но если вдруг найду - сошлюсь.

Answer (score 0):

Для массив не очень большого размера можно делать так:

```
A aa[3] = {{5}, {5}, {5}};
```

К сожалению, препроцессор С++ довольно примитивен, а то можно было бы написать макрос, создающий подобные повторения автоматически. Например, такое позволяет препроцессор ассемблера NASM.

Comment: да, у MASM тоже хороший препроцессор, аналогичные вещи проделать без проблем